# Python3 - Advice on a while loop with range?

Tags: python-3.x

Good afternoon! I am relatively new to Python - and am working on an assignment for a class.

The goal of this code is to download a file, add a line of data to the file, then create a while loop that iterates through each line of data, and prints out the city name and the highest average temp from the data for that city.

My code is below - I have the output working, no problem. The only issue I am running into is an `IndexError: list index out of range` - at the end.

I have searched on StackOverflow - as well as digging into the range() function documentation online with Python. I think I just need to figure to the range() properly, and I'd be done with it.

If I take out the range, I get the same error - so I tried to change the for/in to - for city in mean_temps:
The result of that was that the output only showed 4 of the 7 cities - skipping every other city.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!
here is my code - the screenshot link below shows output and the error as well:

```
!curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/MicrosoftLearning/intropython/master/world_temp_mean.csv -o mean_temp.txt
mean_temps = open('mean_temp.txt', 'a+')
mean_temps.write("Rio de Janeiro,Brazil,30.0,18.0")
mean_temps.seek(0)
headings = mean_temps.readline().split(',')
print(headings)

while mean_temps:
    range(len(city_temp))
    for city in mean_temps:
        city_temp = mean_temps.readline().split(',')
        print(headings[0].capitalize(),"of", city_temp[0],headings[2], "is", city_temp[2], "Celsius")

mean_temps.close()
```

[image: My code!]

Comment: Welcome to the site!  I am glad you have taken the tour.  Would you please see the [how-to-ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and then [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45597960/edit) accordingly?  For example, please include the source inline and not in a screenshot.  Folks are much more likely to help you if they can copy your code and try it themselves.  Thanks, and good luck!

Comment: ok, will do... thanks!

Comment: What do you expect `range(len(city_temp))` to do besides throw a `NameError`?

Comment: Get rid of that line and the while loop. You just need the `for` to correctly iterate over the file.

Comment: The last line is probably blank, leaving you with an empty list, i.e., one that does not have index zero. Do a check for `if city_temp:` before printing.

Comment: Also you should replace `mean_temps.readline().split(',')` with `city.split(',')`. The variable `city` in for loop already contains the line from file.

Answer (score 0):

You have used a `while` loop, when you actually want to use a `for` loop. You have no condition on your `while` loop, therefore, it will evaluate to `True`, and run forever. You should use a `for` loop in the pattern

```
for x in x:
    do stuff
```

In your case, you will want to use

```
for x in range(len(city_temp)):
    for city in means_temp:
```

EDIT:
If you have to use a while loop, you could have variable, `x`, that is incremented by the `while` loop. The `while` loop could run while `x` is less than `range(len(city_temp))`.

A basic example is

```
text = "hi"
counter = 0
while counter < 10:
    print(text)
    counter += 1
```

EDIT 2:
You also said that they expected you to get out of a while loop. If you want a while loop to run forever unless a condition is met later, you can use the [`break` command](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#break) to stop a `while` or `for` loop.

Comment: Thanks for all the feedback - the while loop is a requirement of the assignment, so has to be there. Obviously, that is to make sure we understand how to get OUT of the lop, I am sure... but it means I am painted into a while loop corner. I will try out some of these ideas and see what I come up with - thanks so much!

Comment: ok, trying to add a break in the while loop - and that is causing it to skip every other line of data. There are 9 lines in the txt file total - one header line, and then 8 lines of data (after the part of the code that adds a line with data for Rio) - so the output should have 8 cities and their highest avg temp listed.  I am also waiting on a response from the instructor - but not understanding what is causing the behavior is making me want a drink! LOL

Answer (score 0):

I've been stuck with this as well with the index error.  My original code was:

```
city_temp = mean_temp.readline().strip(" \n").split(",")

while city_temp:
    print("City of",city_temp[0],headings[2],city_temp[2],"Celcius")
    city_temp = mean_temp.readline().split(",")
```

So I read the line then, in the loop, print the line, create the list from reading the line and if the list is empty, or false, break.  Problem is I was getting the same error as yourself and this is because city_temp is still true after reading the last line.  If you add..

```
print(city_temp)
```

to your code you will see that city_temp returns as "" and even though it's an empty string the list has content so will return true.  My best guess (and it is a guess) it looks for the split condition and returns back nothing which then populates the list as an empty string.

The solution I found was to readline into a string first (or at the end of the whole loop) before creating the list:

```
city_temp = mean_temp.readline()

while city_temp:
    city_temp = city_temp.split(',')
    print(headings[0].capitalize(),"of",city_temp[0],headings[2],"is",city_temp[2],"Celcius")
    city_temp = mean_temp.readline()
```

This time city_temp is checked by the while loop as a string and now returns false.  Hope this helps from someone else who struggled with this